# Setting a SwiftUI @EnvironmentObject from outside a view

Tags: ios, swiftui, observable, combine

I'd like to have a worker task update a SwiftUI view.

The worker task is busy doing the procedural work of the application - playing sounds, and firing timer-based events. I'd like to to flash several icons in a SwiftUI view during those timer events. So I want to trigger a view refresh in those icon views.

So, I created an environmentObject called Settings. It's instantiated in the App Delegate, and attached to the root view in the SceneDelegate.

The Settings object works just fine inside the SwiftUI View hierarchy.

The problem is the dreaded:

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Settings found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Settings may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

I think that the problem is that the worker class is instantiated in the AppDelegate, and Settings is not yet an ObservableObject yet when it's instantiated. But I'm confused.

The environment object is straightforward:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class Settings: ObservableObject {
   @Published var showMenu: Bool = true
   @Published var lessonNum: Int = 0

   @Published var arrowsOn: Bool = false {
       willSet {
           willChange.send(self)
       }
   }
}

let willChange = PassthroughSubject<Settings, Never>()
```

It's instantiated, along with the worker class, in the AppDelegate:

```
let settings = Settings()
...
var workerClass  = WorkerClass()
var leftArrow = LeftArrowView()
```

And it's passed to the SceneDelegate:

```
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView
                .environmentObject(settings)
```

The sub view that uses settings looks at the environment object to draw the icon in either the on or off state:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LeftArrowView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var settings: Settings

    let leftArrowOnImage = Image("Arrow Left On").renderingMode(.original)
    let leftArrowOffImage = Image("Arrow Left Off").renderingMode(.original)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if settings.arrowsOn {
                leftArrowOnImage
            } else {
                leftArrowOffImage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The worker class is called as a Button action from higher up in the SwiftUI view hierarchy.

Inside the worker class I attempt to attach to the settings environment object:

```
import Combine

public class WorkerClass : NSObject, ObservableObject {

    @EnvironmentObject var settings: Settings
```

and inside a method that's invoked via a timer, I attempt to update a variable in the environment object:

```
       settings.arrowsOn = !settings.arrowsOn
        print("Arrows are \(settings.arrowsOn)")
```

... which is when I discover that I failed to actually attach properly to the environment object.

What did I miss?

Thanks in advance for any insights...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@EnvironmentObject` wrapper is only to be used inside SwiftUI view, in other places you can use reference types in regular way, so here is possible solution

```
public class WorkerClass : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var settings: Settings    // reference property
```

and when create

```
let settings = Settings()
...
var workerClass  = WorkerClass(settings: settings) // << same settings as in view
```

Comment: Thanks! I can certainly do that, but the purpose of updating the settings object is to cause the SwiftUI view to update. Now I may be quite wrong, but I understand that the purpose of the wrapper is to cause Combine to publish a change to the variable, which the SwiftUI is subscribed to. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Andromeda, the purpose of wrapper is *to observe* published value and update view, that why it is needed *only in view*. And the published property will be published whenever (and from wherever) they modified, that's why it is enough to have a reference to it in your WorkerClass case.

Comment: Ah, that's what I get for not finishing reading the Combine book - thanks!  When I do that, I get a helpful warning not to update a published variable on a background thread (which I'm not) ... but the SwiftUI view still isn't being triggered for view update.  Any idea what might be missing?

Comment: Thank you so much - I definitely owe you a tasty beverage of your choice!