# SwiftUI: Views are not changing after value updated in array

Tags: swift, swiftui

Starter question: I'm trying to get a View to update after variables included in the array [Member] do change. Pressing the button in the code below does not do anything. After reading many similar topics I know this can not work, but I have no idea how solve it.

```
import SwiftUI

class Member: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var value:Int
    
    init(value:Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class Values:ObservableObject {
    @Published var v1:Int = 1
    @Published var v2:Int = 2
    @Published var v3:Int = 3
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var values = Values()
    var items: [Member]
    
    init() {
        items = [Member(value: values.v1), Member(value: values.v2), Member(value: values.v3)]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(items) {i in
                    Text("Value: \(i.value)")
                }
            }
            Button("Change v2 = 0") {
                values.v2 = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, you change Values, which do not join anyhow with Member/s. Rethink what you try to do here, because `v2` is primitive value, it is just copied on assignment.

Comment: @Asperi: You are right. How do change from copying a primitive value to a binding/linking?

Comment: It sounds more like a table relationship. One `Value` is related to multiple `Members`. You might look into using `CoreData`.

Comment: This questions seems similar so check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268309/setting-a-swiftui-environmentobject-from-outside-a-view

Comment: @loremipsum: CoreData does not look like the right solution, as my issue was more about the data flow in the app and not the persistent storage.

Comment: @JonasDeichelmann: Thanks for your suggestion. If this link was giving me some clues, then unfortunately I was not able to understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do...

```
struct Member: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var value: Int
}

class Values: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items = [Member]()
    
    init() {
        items = [Member(value: 1), Member(value: 2), Member(value: 3)]
    }
    
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var values = Values()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(values.items) { item in
                    Text("Value: \(item.value)")
                }
            }
            Button("Change 2nd index = 0") {
                values.items[1].value = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was clearly leading me to the right direction. Getting a basic understanding how ObservableObject, Publish and the updates in the ForEach loop are working was key.